# Is formal verification just duplicating the same logic in two languages for equality?

Tags: automated-testing

I’m trying to wrap my head around why formal verification is useful.

I’ve read that it reduces vulnerabilities in code, but I’m puzzled by how it can do that.

My understanding is you write a specification in another language that you can use to test your implementation for conformity to the spec, but to me that alone wouldn’t make code better.

What am I missing? Or is that the whole picture?

I’ve read that multilingual people tend to be more logical, is the idea behind formal methods the same? Is it as simple as writing the same problem in two languages forcing you to think about the problem clearer?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "formal testing" and "formal verification"? What is your understanding of the terms? Can you share reference from where you read about these terms?

Comment: What I mean is like the sel4 operating system having Isabelle proofs written in conjunction with the code. My understanding of the terms is when you use math to exhaustively test your code without the pit falls of unit testing that can only test a particular case of potentially an uncomputable amount of other cases